# Group and Sub group element nodes of same row with predefined file format

Tags: xml, xslt, transform, xslt-2.0

I'm facing an issue with the xslt and have no idea how to transform the below XML in to desired output.
How to read the elements of similar nodes and generate the output in same line based on a condition?
Also, The O/P File has predefined format.

XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Plan Id="01">
      <Ledger>1</Ledger>
      <Product>PRD-AAA</Product>      
      <Order_Amount>2480</Order_Amount>
      <Invoice_Amount>496</Invoice_Amount>
</Plan>
<Plan Id="02">
      <Ledger>2</Ledger>
      <Product>PRD-BBB</Product>      
      <Order_Amount>9000</Order_Amount>
      <Invoice_Amount>3000</Invoice_Amount>
</Plan>
<Plan Id="03">
      <Product Id="PRD-X">
         <Ledger>1</Ledger>  
         <Order_Amount>4500</Order_Amount>
     <Invoice_Amount>1650</Invoice_Amount>
      </Product>
      <Product Id="PRD-Y">
     <Ledger>1</Ledger>         
         <Order_Amount>550</Order_Amount>
         <Invoice_Amount>866</Invoice_Amount>
      </Product>
      <Product Id="PRD-Z">
         <Ledger>2</Ledger>  
         <Order_Amount>5000</Order_Amount>
         <Invoice_Amount>1000</Invoice_Amount>
      </Product>
      <Product Id="PRD-A">
         <Ledger>3</Ledger>  
         <Order_Amount>2500</Order_Amount>
         <Invoice_Amount>1000</Invoice_Amount>
      </Product>
</Plan>
```

***Columns of the CSV files are*** (No need to print the column header) this is just to understand the O/P file format.
`Plan Details,Plan ID,Ledger#,Product Code,Amounts,Order Amount,Invoice Amount,STATICTEXTFILLER1,STATICTEXTFILLER2,,Plan ID,Ledger#,Product Code,Amounts,Order Amount,Invoice Amount,STATICTEXTFILLER3`

**Rules:**
1) STATICTEXTFILLER1,STATICTEXTFILLER2 will come after the first Invoice amount

2) STATICTEXTFILLER13 is at the end of the last Invoice amount

3) If plan 03 had only one product in Ledger# the remaining details on the file should left blank except the STATICTEXTFILLER1,STATICTEXTFILLER3,STATICTEXTFILLER3

**Expected Output** 
[image]
`Plan Details,01,1,PRD-AAA,Amounts,2480,496,STATICTEXTFILLER1,STATICTEXTFILLER2,,,,Amounts,,,STATICTEXTFILLER3
Plan Details,02,2,PRD-BBB,Amounts,9000,3000,STATICTEXTFILLER1,STATICTEXTFILLER2,,,,Amounts,,,STATICTEXTFILLER3
Plan Details,03,1,PRD-X,Amounts,4500,1650,STATICTEXTFILLER1,STATICTEXTFILLER2,03,1,PRD-Y,Amounts,550,866,STATICTEXTFILLER3
Plan Details,03,2,PRD-Z,Amounts,5000,1000,STATICTEXTFILLER1,STATICTEXTFILLER2,,,,Amounts,,,STATICTEXTFILLER3
Plan Details,03,3,PRD-A,Amounts,2500,1000,STATICTEXTFILLER1,STATICTEXTFILLER2,,,,Amounts,,,STATICTEXTFILLER3`

Comment: An example does not always explain the rule. It seems like within each plan, you want to **group** products of the same ledger number in the same row. If this is so, then this is just another exercise in [Muenchian grouping](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html). Note that your XML is missing a root element.

Comment: Yes, Within each Plan i would like to group based on the Ledger number on a same record. However the Plan 03 had a different structure.

Comment: Yes, I have noticed that. So how does one know which structure each plan will have?

Comment: There are only 3 plans in which Plan 03 had multiple products. Plan 01 and Plan 02 will always only one product. The XML Root element is <Report_Data>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<s>Your source didn't have a root element so I just chose:</s>

**Edit**: Updated root element as mentioned in comment

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Report_Data>
<Plan Id="01">
    <Ledger>1</Ledger>
    <Product>PRD-AAA</Product>      
    <Order_Amount>2480</Order_Amount>
    <Invoice_Amount>496</Invoice_Amount>
</Plan>
<Plan Id="02">
    <Ledger>2</Ledger>
    <Product>PRD-BBB</Product>      
    <Order_Amount>9000</Order_Amount>
    <Invoice_Amount>3000</Invoice_Amount>
</Plan>
<Plan Id="03">
    <Product Id="PRD-X">
        <Ledger>1</Ledger>  
        <Order_Amount>4500</Order_Amount>
        <Invoice_Amount>1650</Invoice_Amount>
    </Product>
    <Product Id="PRD-Y">
        <Ledger>1</Ledger>         
        <Order_Amount>550</Order_Amount>
        <Invoice_Amount>866</Invoice_Amount>
    </Product>
    <Product Id="PRD-Z">
        <Ledger>2</Ledger>  
        <Order_Amount>5000</Order_Amount>
        <Invoice_Amount>1000</Invoice_Amount>
    </Product>
    <Product Id="PRD-A">
        <Ledger>3</Ledger>  
        <Order_Amount>2500</Order_Amount>
        <Invoice_Amount>1000</Invoice_Amount>
    </Product>
</Plan>
</Report_Data>
```

With this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" exclude-result-prefixes="xs" version="2.0">
<xsl:output method="text"/>

<xsl:template match="Report_Data">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="Plan"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Plan">
    <xsl:choose>
        <!-- Plan type 1, Id 1 and 2 -->
        <xsl:when test="not(Product/@Id)">
            <xsl:value-of select="@Id,Ledger,Product,Order_Amount,Invoice_Amount" separator=","/>
            <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:when>
        <!-- Plan type 2, Id 3-->
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:for-each-group select="Product" group-by="Ledger">
                <xsl:value-of
                    select="for $i in current-group() return ($i/../@Id,$i/Ledger,$i/@Id,$i/Order_Amount,$i/Invoice_Amount)"
                    separator=","/>
                <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
            </xsl:for-each-group>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I get:

```
01,1,PRD-AAA,2480,496
02,2,PRD-BBB,9000,3000
03,1,PRD-X,4500,1650,03,1,PRD-Y,550,866
03,2,PRD-Z,5000,1000
03,3,PRD-A,2500,1000
```

Basically the `value-of's` select the sequence of elements in the order you want to display them depending which plan type you have. With xslt-2.0 you can save yourself the delimeter and use the value-of's seprartor attribute instead.

Answer (score 2):

> There are only 3 plans in which Plan 03 had multiple products. Plan 01
>   and Plan 02 will always only one product.

That's a strange way to organize data. Anyway, try the following:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8"/>

<xsl:key name="product3-by-ledger" match="Plan[@Id='03']/Product" use="Ledger" />

<xsl:variable name="LF" select="'&#xA;'" />
<xsl:variable name="delim" select="','" />

<xsl:template match="/">
    <!-- Plans 01 & 02 -->
    <xsl:for-each select="Report_Data/Plan[@Id='01' or @Id='02']">
        <xsl:value-of select="concat(@Id, $delim, Ledger, $delim, Product, $delim, Order_Amount, $delim, Invoice_Amount, $LF)"/>
    </xsl:for-each>
    <!-- Plan 03 -->
    <!-- for each distinct ledger -->
    <xsl:for-each select="/Report_Data/Plan[@Id='03']/Product[count(. | key('product3-by-ledger', Ledger)[1]) = 1]">
            <!--get products with same ledger -->
        <xsl:for-each select="key('product3-by-ledger', Ledger)">
            <xsl:value-of select="concat(../@Id, $delim, Ledger, $delim, @Id, $delim, Order_Amount, $delim, Invoice_Amount)"/>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <xsl:if test="position()!=last()">
            <xsl:value-of select="$LF"/>
        </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Edit:**
If you are using XSLT 2.0, go with `<xsl:for-each-group>` as suggested in the other answer, instead of Muenchian grouping.

---

### Added:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8"/>

<xsl:key name="product3-by-ledger" match="Plan[@Id='03']/Product" use="Ledger" />

<xsl:variable name="LF" select="'&#xA;'" />
<xsl:variable name="delim" select="','" />

<xsl:template match="/">
    <!-- Plans 01 & 02 -->
    <xsl:for-each select="Report_Data/Plan[@Id='01' or @Id='02']">
        <xsl:value-of select="concat(@Id, $delim, Ledger, $delim, Product, $delim, Order_Amount, $delim, Invoice_Amount, $delim, 'STATICTEXTFILLER1,STATICTEXTFILLER2,STATICTEXTFILLER3', $LF)"/>
    </xsl:for-each>
    <!-- Plan 03 -->
    <!-- for each distinct ledger -->
    <xsl:for-each select="/Report_Data/Plan[@Id='03']/Product[count(. | key('product3-by-ledger', Ledger)[1]) = 1]">
            <!--get products with same ledger -->
        <xsl:for-each select="key('product3-by-ledger', Ledger)">
            <xsl:value-of select="concat(../@Id, $delim, Ledger, $delim, @Id, $delim, Order_Amount, $delim, Invoice_Amount, $delim)"/>
            <xsl:if test="position()=1">
                <xsl:text>STATICTEXTFILLER1,STATICTEXTFILLER2,</xsl:text>
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:if test="position()=last()">
                <xsl:text>STATICTEXTFILLER3</xsl:text>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <xsl:if test="position()!=last()">
            <xsl:value-of select="$LF"/>
        </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The above stylesheet, when applied to a **corrected** input of:

```
<Report_Data>
    <Plan Id="01">
          <Ledger>1</Ledger>
          <Product>PRD-AAA</Product>      
          <Order_Amount>2480</Order_Amount>
          <Invoice_Amount>496</Invoice_Amount>
    </Plan>
    <Plan Id="02">
          <Ledger>2</Ledger>
          <Product>PRD-BBB</Product>      
          <Order_Amount>9000</Order_Amount>
          <Invoice_Amount>3000</Invoice_Amount>
    </Plan>
    <Plan Id="03">
          <Product Id="PRD-X">
             <Ledger>1</Ledger>  
             <Order_Amount>4500</Order_Amount>
         <Invoice_Amount>1650</Invoice_Amount>
          </Product>
          <Product Id="PRD-Y">
         <Ledger>1</Ledger>         
             <Order_Amount>550</Order_Amount>
             <Invoice_Amount>866</Invoice_Amount>
          </Product>
          <Product Id="PRD-Z">
             <Ledger>2</Ledger>  
             <Order_Amount>5000</Order_Amount>
             <Invoice_Amount>1000</Invoice_Amount>
          </Product>
          <Product Id="PRD-A">
             <Ledger>3</Ledger>  
             <Order_Amount>2500</Order_Amount>
             <Invoice_Amount>1000</Invoice_Amount>
          </Product>
    </Plan>
</Report_Data>
```

will produce:

```
01,1,PRD-AAA,2480,496,STATICTEXTFILLER1,STATICTEXTFILLER2,STATICTEXTFILLER3
02,2,PRD-BBB,9000,3000,STATICTEXTFILLER1,STATICTEXTFILLER2,STATICTEXTFILLER3
03,1,PRD-X,4500,1650,STATICTEXTFILLER1,STATICTEXTFILLER2,03,1,PRD-Y,550,866,STATICTEXTFILLER3
03,2,PRD-Z,5000,1000,STATICTEXTFILLER1,STATICTEXTFILLER2,STATICTEXTFILLER3
03,3,PRD-A,2500,1000,STATICTEXTFILLER1,STATICTEXTFILLER2,STATICTEXTFILLER3
```

Comment: What if i want to add some static text in between?

Comment: @user2992769 In between what?

Comment: What if i want to add some static text in between? for example,                
    Plan Details,03,1,PRD-X,Amounts,4500,1650,STATICTEXTFILLER1,STATICTEXTFILLER2,03,1,PRD-Y,Amounts,550,866,STATICTEXTFILLER3

Comment: @user2992769 Just add the literal text as another argument to the concat() function, e.g. `concat('Plan Details', @Id, $delim, Ledger, ... )`.

Comment: the STATICFILLER 1 &2 should be after the PRD-X amounts and STATICFILLER 3 should be after PRD-Y amounts. But the following code gives me,
`concat('Plan Details',$delim,../@Id, $delim, Ledger, $delim, @Id, $delim,'Amount',$delim,Order_Amount, $delim, Invoice_Amount,STATICTEXTFILLER1,STATICTEXTFILLER2) `

Plan Details,03,1,PRD-X,Amounts,4500,1650,STATICTEXTFILLER1,STATICTEXTFILLER2,Plan Details,03,1,PRD-Y,Amounts,550,866,STATICTEXTFILLER1,STATICTEXTFILLER2

Comment: @user2992769 I think you need to edit your question. My answer looks **only** at the ledger number, and puts **any** matching product in that line. If you have specific rules for specific products (by Product Id), you need to state them explicitly.

Comment: @user2992769 Yes, but I still don't understand it. Please state the **rules** by which the output is produced. For example, does STATICTEXTFILLER1,STATICTEXTFILLER2 come after the **first** Invoice_Amount, or after **every** Invoice_Amount except the last? And so on.

Comment: **Rules:**
1) STATICTEXTFILLER1,STATICTEXTFILLER2 will come after the first Invoice amount
2) STATICTEXTFILLER13 is at the end of the last Invoice amount
3) If plan 03 had only one product in Ledger# the remaining details on the file should left blank except the STATICTEXTFILLER1,STATICTEXTFILLER3,STATICTEXTFILLER3

Comment: @user2992769 I am sorry, but you're not being clear and I don't have time for these negotiations. I have added a modified stylesheet to my answer that returns what I *think* is what you want. If not, then you will need to work on it - I don't think it's that hard.